Discrepancy using two ways to calculate bisected lengths of the base of a triangle by the height
I have a triangle with three side lengths known $\,a=1.2 b=1.54\,$ and the base $\,c=2.44.\,$ I can calculate the height from vertex $\,c\,$ to the line joining ab as $\,h=0.67122.\,$ Height is the perpendicular distance from the vertex to the base $\,c.\,$ I have checked this height with online calculators and it seems to match.
My question is to do with the lengths that this height line divides the base into, say m and $\,n.\,$ One can think of two approaches to figure out $\,m\,$ and $\,n.\,$
First approach using Pythagorean theorem:
$\,m^2 = a^2 - h^2 = 1.2^2 - 0.67122^2 = 0.989464.\,$ Square rooting, we get
$\,m =0.994718\,$
Second approach using proportionality: h would divide $\,c\,$ in the same proportions as $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$
so $\,(1.2/2.74)* 2.44 = 1.068613\,$
Similarly, I can calculate $\,n.\,$ In both approaches $\,m+n=c.\,$ However, the answers by the two approaches are quite different in that the $\,m\,$ and $\,n\,$ values are different. I have checked my work but cannot figure out why there is a discrepancy (unless I made a mistake with proportionality assumption).

It is not true that "h would divide c in the same proportions as a and b". That only works for the angle bisector.

One segment is found by projection of $~a$ on $c$; the other part $ b \cos A $ is found similarly.
$$ a \cos B= a\cdot \frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2 a c}$$
Also the the altitude does not divide $c$ in the ratio $a:b~$;
It is the bisector of $\angle C$ that has such a property.

Thanks for your answer, I just realized this too.

Perhaps to avoid using calculators, you can use the mystical Heron's formula to calculate any of the three altitudes. As others have said, however, this still won't patch the proportionality concerns.
